# Calling javascript functions from webview Android

Tags: javascript, android

I have a webview and it is loaded with a html file.

Now that I want to call the Javascript function DataInput() from the webview.

Here is my code.But the console returns

```
E/Web Console(435): Uncaught ReferenceError: DataInput is not defined:1
```

Does anybody know why? Thanks!

```
WebView engine = (WebView) (findViewById(R.id.webView1));

    engine.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    engine.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
          public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
                Log.d("MyApplication", cm.message() + " -- From line "
                                     + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
                                     + cm.sourceId() );
                return true;
              }
            });
    engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    engine.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

    engine.loadUrl("file:///" + path);
    engine.loadUrl("javascript:DataInput()");
```

My html files includes the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function DataInput( )
{   
  $( "video" ).each( function(e){this.play();}   );
  $( "video" ).bind( "ended", function(e){this.play();});
}
</script>
```

FURTHER EDIT:::::

I added a button and calls the JS upon onclick and it (kinda) worked... i.e.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    engine.loadUrl("javascript:DataInput()");

}
```

How come???? I really really do want to know why.....

P.S. I said (kinda) work because the video did autoplay (due to $( "video" ).each( function(e){this.play();}   );) but does not loop ($( "video" ).bind( "ended", function(e){this.play();}); <<< not working)

Comment: do u have the correct file at the specified location i.e., `path` and have u defined the function `DataInput()` in the file located at the specified `path`?

Comment: I have attached my javascript code for your reference, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your Javascript to this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="location_of_your_jquery_file" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.gotofunc = function () {
        $("video").each(function (e) {
            this.play();
        });
        $("video").bind("ended", function (e) {
            this.play();
        });
    };

    function DataInput() {
        $.fn.gotofunc();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: see this tutorial hope it help.
http://android-
er.blogspot.com/2011/10/call-
javascript-inside-webview-
from.html?m=1

Comment: @user1702061 Have you added your jquery_location in `src` attribute?

Comment: jquery_location? Do you mean the jquery file?

Comment: yup. to use jquery statements you need refer the jquery file

Comment: already referred ..... I have included the jquery file in the html document and also have put the file at the same location as the html file....